# How to add blank element to an array based on value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array and a variable,the variable will show the integer value,based on that value I need to add blank element to the array.For example value is 4 so I should get result ['','','','','chart1','chart2','chartr3']. Here is the code below,here I hardcoded for example

### HTML

```
<p>How to add blank element to an array based on value in javascript</p>
```

### SCRIPT

```
var count = 4;
var array = ['chart1','chart2','chartr3'];
console.log(array);
var finalarray[] ;
console.log(finalarray);//['','','','','chart1','chart2','chartr3'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [unshift](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp)

```
var array = ['chart1','chart2','chartr3'];
var count = 4;

for (var i = 1; i++; i <= count) {
   array.unshift(' ');
}
```

Edit. To fire this in each click (jquery)

```
var start_array = ['chart1','chart2','chartr3'];

$('.element-clicked').on('click', function(e) {
    start_array.unshift(' ');
});
```

Comment: Is it possible without for loop,if I use it on click a button,blank array is keep increasing based on click

Comment: @UIAPPDEVELOPER Is this a question? I do not understand

Comment: Yes,can I get the output  without using for loop

Comment: Ehm, yes... when you fired the click, you can do array.unshift(' '); for each click. But in this case, "array" var must be global. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying a loop?

```
var count = 4;
var array = ["chart1", "chart2", "chart3"];

var finalArray = array;

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    finalArray.unshift("");
}

console.log(finalArray);
```

**Note:** The *unshift()* method does not work properly in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier: the values will be inserted, but the return value will be undefined.

If you want this array to increment when clicking a button you could try something like this:

```js
var array = ["after", "after2", "after3"];

// This will set the span 'originalArray' to display 'array'
document.getElementById("originalArray").innerHTML = array;  

// prependValueToArray:
// - This function will add a value e.g: "" to your specified array 'x' number of times.
function prependValueToArray(array, number, value) {
    var resultArray = array;

    for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        resultArray.unshift(value);
    }
    
    // This will change the value inside the 'resultArray' span to the new array
    document.getElementById("resultArray").innerHTML = resultArray;  
}
```

```html
<p>
  <strong>
    Original:
  </strong>
  <br/>
  [
  <span id="originalArray"></span>
  ]
</p>

<button onclick="prependValueToArray(array, 1, 'before');">Click me!</button>

<p>
  <strong>
    Result:
  </strong>
  <br/>
  [
  <span id="resultArray"></span>
  ]
</p>
```

Comment: Is it possible without for loop,if I use it on click a button,blank array is keep increasing based on click

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use a function. and var finalarray[] ; is wrong.

```js
var array = ["chart1","chart2","chartr3"];
var count = 4;
function myFunction() {

 var finalarray=[] ;
    
  for(var i=0;i< 4;i++){
   finalarray.push("") ;
  
}
 finalarray.push("chart1") ;
  finalarray.push("chart2") ;
   finalarray.push("chartr3") ;
console.log(finalarray);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

var count = 4;
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {

finalarray[i] = '';

}